# JQuery how to make transition on setTimeout text change

Tags: jquery

how do I make every text change have a fadein and fade out transition, if I give a 5 second interval how do I give a fade out and fade in

```
let timer = 0;
do_test(timer);

function do_test(timer){
  timer++;
  if (timer > 29){
    $('body').css('background','blue');
  }else if (timer > 20){
    $('body').css('background','green');
  }else if (timer > 10){
    $('body').css('background','pink');
  }else if (timer > 3){
    $('body').css('background','yellow');
  }
  $('#cnt').text(timer);
  if (timer < 40){
    setTimeout(() => {do_test(timer)},500);
  } else {
    $('body').html('<div id="dun">DONE</div>');
  }
}
```

this html

```
<div id="cnt"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fadeIn and fadeOut

```js
let timer = 0;
do_test(timer);
const body = $("body");

function do_test(timer){
  timer++;
  const elem = $("#cnt");
  elem.fadeOut(500, function () {
    elem.text(timer);
    if (timer===10) body.css('background','green');
    else if (timer===25) body.css('background','yellow');
    else if (timer===30) body.css('background','red');
    elem.fadeIn(500, function () {
      if (timer < 50) do_test(timer);
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  transition: background .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cnt"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setInterval` for this.

```js
const $body = $('body'), 
      cnt = $('#cnt');   
let i = 0,
do_test = setInterval(function() {
  i++;
  if (i > 0 && i < 2) setBg($body, 'blue');
  else if (i >2 && i < 4) setBg($body, 'green');
  else if (i > 4 && i < 6) setBg($body, 'pink');
  else if (i > 6 && i < 8) setBg($body, 'yellow');
  if(i == 9){
    clearInterval(do_test);
    setBg($body, 'white');
    fadeText('DONE');
  }else {
    fadeText(i);
  }
},1000);

function fadeText(text){
  cnt.css('opacity', 0);
  setTimeout(function() {
    cnt.text(text);
    cnt.css('opacity', 1);
  }, 500);
}

function setBg(sel, col){
  sel.css('background',col);
}
```

```css
body {
  transition: background .3s ease;
}

#cnt {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 100px;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cnt"></div>
```